# android content Length() return -1

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2, content-length, http-content-length

I  download file from server. but when i want get size of file always  `body.contentLength()` return -1 . some ways fix this issue with `HttpUrlConnection` but how about `ResponseBody` class ?

```
  private void initDownload(){

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://mobleh.com/").build();    
        RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);    
        Call<ResponseBody> request = requestInterface.getAPK(path);

        try {    
            downloadFile(request.execute().body());

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    private void downloadFile(ResponseBody body) throws IOException {

        int count;
        byte data[] = new byte[1024 * 4];            
        long fileSize = body.contentLength();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after some research and thinking i made some trick , just get size of file with HttpURLConnection like this :

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(path).openConnection();

    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");

long fileSize = connection.getContentLength();
```

with this way dos not matter which way you download files , always can get your size like this .